# Presentation: problem with figure captions

Tags: beamer, captions, presentations

I am using LaTeX to make a presentation and I do not want to have captions labeled "Figure 1: " etc., so I followed the help from this page:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
```

that worked fine and I got only mine caption without "Figure:" before it. However, when I load the package `subcaption` (which I need because I am also doing subfigures), the above command stops working and it shows "Figure:" before the captions. Is there any way to use a package `subcaption` and be able to get rid of those at the same time in presentation?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use the interface `caption` and `subcaption` provide. Is that all you wanted to know? You don't give any code, so I assume so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `subcaption` package, you can use the mechanism of the `caption` package to change the appearance of the captions

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```